# How to insert meta keyword to search result page

Tags: search

I have search a lot but cannot find any solution for my problem.

I when i entered the search term to the search box of my website, it goes to `mysite.com/search/search+term`. However, the result page does not have meta keywords and meta description. I trying to find way to add these values into the header of the result page with `meta keywords = search term` and `meta description = information about the search term`.

I think i will need to modify the search.php or query.php files, but not sure how to do. I don't want to change the header.php because it will conflict with other normal posts.

Anyone has any suggestion how to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is relatively easy. you can add this to your theme's functions.php file

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tags');
function add_meta_tags(){

  if(is_search()){
    $search_keyword = get_search_query();
    echo '<meta name="META_NAME" content="META TESTING" />';
  }
}
```

you may change `echo '<meta name="META_NAME" content="META TESTING" />';` as you want to output the meta tags.

however, your theme needs to call `wp_head();` for this to work. check your theme's `header.php` file.

Comment: Thank you very much, HungryCoder! It works almost perfectly. The only problem exists is the outcome is 2 meta value being continuous in a line, something like this `<meta name="keyword" content="keyword"><meta name="description" content="description>`. Is there any way to separate the 2 meta value in two line separately? Since i'm not sure if it affect SEO

Comment: That's very easy. `echo '<meta name="META_NAME" content="META TESTING" />'.PHP_EOL;`. however, both in same line is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific solution depends on how your header.php file currently implements those two meta tags (static, filtered, etc.).

The simplest solution is to edit your header.php file but wrap your changes in the is_search() function:

`<?php if ( is_search() ) : ?> . . . <?php else: ?> . . . <?php endif; ?>`

The more graceful (/complicated) solution would be to filter the output with a custom filter.